# Correct way to register a global event

Tags: kentico

I need to register a custom *global event* that will be executed before updating `RoleInfo` objects in *Kentico 11 CMS*.

Documentation states this:

> event class.event action.event type += handler method name

Where:

> **Event class** – event classes are containers of events related to groups of functionality
>   **Event action** – represents a specific action
>   that occurs within the system
>   **Event type**  – determines when exactly the
>   event takes place, typically Before or After the action. Some actions
>   only have one type: Execute

Regarding this, is the correct way to register the event I need? If not, explanation would be appreciated as this part of documentation remains unclear for me.

```
RoleInfoProvider.Events.Update.Before += MyMethod
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Object events are events that can be registered for all classes that inherit from AbstractInfo base class such as UserInfo, RoleInfo, SiteInfo and more. So in your case RoleInfoProvider is not inheriting from AsbtractInfo class.

You should use

```
RoleInfo.TYPEINFO.Events.Update.Before += YourMethod
```

You should also initialize it in your custom module class, eg.

```
[assembly: RegisterModule(typeof(CompanyOverviewModule))]
```

public class CompanyOverviewModule : Module
{

```
public CompanyOverviewModule()
    : base("CompanyOverview")
{
}

// Initializes the module. Called when the application starts.
protected override void OnInit()
{
    base.OnInit();


   RoleInfo.TYPEINFO.Events.Update.Before += Role_UpdateBefore;
}

private void Role_UpdateBefore(object sender, ObjectEventArgs e)
{
    RoleInfo ri = (RoleInfo)e.Object;

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Info provider is a class that allows you to manipulate with objects. What you are most likely looking for are events for info object. With Roles event handler would look like:

RoleInfo.TYPEINFO.Events.Update.Before += RoleInfo_Update_Before;

Documentation is a bit generic on that part and you are based on your example working with global object event rather than just global events so you can access object events via object TYPEINFO. Global events tend to have their own classes such as RequestEvents or URLRewriting events.

Do not forget to register event handler within HTTP module and to use correct attribute to register it properly.